# Z-index: How to make nested elements appear underneath their parent element

Tags: css, nested, z-index

This fiddle should demonstrate the issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/5sqxQ/2/

I want the sub menu to appear underneath the parent menu.  I was then was looking to extend this with JavaScript to slide the menu from underneath on hover of the parent li element.

Not fussed about the JavaScript but can't figure out how to style the elements to achieve the desired layering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't.

Instead, make the `a` be the "Sign In" "button".

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/5sqxQ/15/

Answer (score 12):

It doesn't work because you are applying a z-index to the parent element which makes the child element stack relative to the other elements *within the parent*.

> Once you assign an element a value for
>   z-index (other than auto), that
>   element establishes its own local
>   stacking context. This means that all
>   of the element's descendants have
>   their own stacking order, relative to
>   the ancestor element.

So if the parent has `z-index: 9` and the child is `z-index: 8`, it's kind of like assigning a z-index of `9, 8`

See [the article here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/web2/css/ch09_05.htm) for a better explanation.

If you remove the z-index on the parent and set the sibling element to `z-index: -1`, that should work. I'm not sure about all browsers, but it works in Chrome anyway.

Here is the  [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shooter/5sqxQ/16/)

Hope that helps.

Comment: `z-index: -1` is alluring, but unpleasant. See: http://jsfiddle.net/5sqxQ/17/ - all I've done is add the wrapper `div` with a background.

Comment: Thanks for ease of implementation i went with thirtydot's answer below.  I didn't really want to muck about with -ve z-index.  Would be too painful.

Comment: whats unpleasant about using a negative z-index? Any integer is perfectly valid. And imho, it actually reads better *semantically* if you want something to appear behind its parent (you're moving the child backwards, instead of moving the parent forwards)

Comment: Did you look at the updated demo (http://jsfiddle.net/5sqxQ/17/)? The red background completely covering the element with `z-index: -1` is *unpleasant*.

Comment: Thanks all.  All i meant was that i was unsure of the cross browser issues for -ve z-index so went with the path of least resistance.  Deadlines and all that...

Comment: @thirtydot: ok i see what you are saying now - it's a fragile solution. *unpleasant* is a strange choice of word though.

Comment: I should have said "`z-index: -1` is alluring, but [it has an] unpleasant [side effect]". That's what I meant, anyway. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the parent and siblings containers position to relative.
Its worked for me before.

Comment: And set the zindex of the parent container as well.

Comment: Sometimes you also have to set the top/left/bottom right locations, usually just top and left will do.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the rules below for how elements are stacked and you can easily come up with your own solution.

ex. Like thirtydot said, give "Sign In" `.users > li > a` a position, `relative` or `absolute`, and `z-index: 1`

[The Stacking order and stacking context rules below are from this link](https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/)

## Stacking Order within a Stacking Context

The order of elements:

1. The stacking context’s root element (the `<html>` element is the only stacking context by default, but any element can be a root element for a stacking context, see rules below)

   - **You cannot put a child element behind a root stacking context element**
2. Positioned elements (and their children) with negative z-index values (higher values are stacked in front of lower values; elements with the same value are stacked according to appearance in the HTML)
3. Non-positioned elements (ordered by appearance in the HTML)
4. Positioned elements (and their children) with a z-index value of auto (ordered by appearance in the HTML)
5. Positioned elements (and their children) with positive z-index values (higher values are stacked in front of lower values; elements with the same value are stacked according to appearance in the HTML)

## When a Stacking Context is Formed

- When an element is the root element of a document (the `<html>` element)
- When an element has a position value other than static **and** a z-index value other than auto
- When an element has an opacity value less than 1
- Several newer CSS properties also create stacking contexts. These include: transforms, filters, css-regions, paged media, and possibly others. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context
- As a general rule, it seems that if a CSS property requires rendering in an offscreen context, it must create a new stacking context.