# Problems with z-index

Tags: javascript, html, css, z-index

I know there are a lot of questions on z-index around here, but I am using z-index for a while now and it always worked fine, but now I'm struggling on this one and I just don't understand why it isn't working because I think I did all necessary steps.

*test.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js " type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.boxGrid').hover(function(){
                    $(".boxCaption", this).stop().animate({bottom:'0px'},{queue:false,duration:300});
                }, function() {
                    $(".boxCaption", this).stop().animate({bottom:'-121px'},{queue:false,duration:300});
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="position: relative; width: 226px; height: 246px;">
            <div class="boxGrid">
                <div class="buttonBack blogImg">
                    <div class="boxCaption">
                        <h3>Top-Blog</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*style.css*

```
.boxGrid
{
    width: 226px;
    height: 246px;
    background-image: url(buttonBorder.png);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 100;
}

.buttonBack
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 12px;
    left: 13px;
    border: 0px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 223px;
    z-index: 50;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.blogImg
{
    background-image: url(blogButton.png);
}

.boxCaption
{ 
    position: absolute;  
    background: url(caption.png);
    height: 121px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: -121px;
    text-align: center;
}

.boxCaption h3
{
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

So I want this `.boxGrid` class to be above the `.buttonBack` class, I added `position:` properties to all div's that are using z-index.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xU8hG/) so the red box needs to be behind the blue one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you make a minimal jsfiddle? That's a little much to digest this early in the morning

Comment: Child elements stack relative to their parent element.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493865/z-index-how-to-make-nested-elements-appear-underneath-their-parent-element
The solution is to move your `.buttonBack` outside of `.boxGrid`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the div.buttonBack as a child to the div.boxGrid. You may need to reorder the HTML.

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 226px; height: 246px;">
    <div class="buttonBack></div>
    <div class="boxGrid">
        <div blogImg">
            <div class="boxCaption">
              <h3>Top-Blog</h3>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't "hide" child element under its parent, because when you're setting z-index for parent, the child is also affected. Just make them siblings.

```
 <div style="position: relative; width: 226px; height: 246px;">
    <div class="boxGrid"></div>
    <div class="buttonBack blogImg">
        <div class="boxCaption">
            <h3>Top-Blog</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Look at this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZwC9n/

Comment: Of course... How could I have been so stupid? :) Thanks! I wasn't thinkink clearly... I'll accept Pais answer, just because he was earlier. don't know which to choose. :)

Comment: Thanks the acception! Some times our minds can become muddled from staring at code for too long.